# Updating a queryset

Tags: django

I'm trying to update columns with new information but I am getting the error: "'instancemethod' object is not iterable" and I can't figure out why.

The error happens when this function is called:

```
def update():
tests = Stock.objects.all
for test in tests:
    tick = test.ticker
    mo2 = get_dividend_per_share(tick)
    moy = get_dividend_yield(tick)
    mo3 = 1 * (Decimal(moy) / 100)
    mop = get_price_earnings_growth_ratio(tick)
    mod = Stock(price=mo, divps=mo2, divpd=mo3, peg=mop)
    mod.save()
```

I am relatively new to Django, am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a small typo, you missed the function call:

```
tests = Stock.objects.all()
```

If you prod around in an interactive shell you can see that:

```
>>> type(Stock.objects.all)
<type 'instancemethod'>
```

while invoking the `all()` method will return an `iterable` object, namely a Django `QuerySet`.

Comment: /headdesk  I can't believe I didn't see that.  Thank you so much for your help! I spent way too much time on a typo!